# Perl: script and module calling a second module

Tags: perl, module

I have the following:

#### Module1

```
package module1;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(<list of subs within>);

use Module2;

sub M1S1 ()
{
  $x = M2S1();
}
```

#### Module 2

```
package module2;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(<list of modules within>);
sub M2S1()
{
...
}

sub M2S2()
{
...
}
```

#### Script

```
use Module2;
use Module1;

$y = M1S1();
$z = M2S2();
```

When the script calls a sub in `Module 1` which in turn calls a sub in `Module 2`, the sub is not found, even though the script can call those subs directly.

I'm not a beginner to Perl by any means, but I've never fully gotten the hang of modules. Our environment has gotten very dependent on `module2`, so I don't want to make any changes that would require changing all the scripts that use it. `Module1` has limited use so I can make changes to it if necessary.

Comment: For one thing, module names are case sensitive, so you don't want to say `package module2;` ... `use Module2;`. Even if this "works", say, on Windows, you will quickly run into issues.

Comment: Tip: `our @ISA = qw(Exporter);` is a backwards approach that's been replaced with `use Exporter qw( import );` a decade ago!

Comment: Please be clear about what your modules' file names and package names are. You have `module2`, `Module2` and `Module 2`, and if you are really using all of those variations then it is no wonder your code doesn't work. Do your module files end with `.pm`?

Comment: You mustn't use prototypes on Perl functions. Just `sub M1S1 { ... }` etc. is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The file name, the name in the package directive, and the name in the `use` statement must match, and that includes case.

```
 Module1.pm
 package Module1;
 use Module1;
```

Or if you had a non-flat namespace,

```
 Foo/Bar.pm
 package Foo::Bar;
 use Foo::Bar;
```

Note that you can have similar [problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639) when you have two exporting modules that use each other (directly or indirectly), but that doesn't seem to the case.

---

```
$ cat Module1.pm
package Module1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( M1S1 );
use Module2;
sub M1S1 { M2S1() }
1;

$ cat Module2.pm
package Module2;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( M2S1 M2S2 );
sub M2S1 { "M2S1" }
sub M2S2 { "M2S2" }
1;

$ cat script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module2;
use Module1;
print(M1S1(), "\n");
print(M2S2(), "\n");

$ ./script.pl
M2S1
M2S2
```